# Showing an image or text for few seconds using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a web app: front-end in Angular and back-end in Rails.
When users are done with filling out the application, they need to press "save" button to save the data.

Right now, when the user clicks the button, there is currently no feedback. When the button is clicked, I wanna show either text or image which says "Data Saved" for 2 seconds.

I would like to add code, but I have no idea how to even start with this. If anyone knows how to do this with Angular or Javascript, please let me know!

Comment: No one can help you until you show your code.  At least show us what you have now.

Comment: need way more info, but feel free to look up docs on $timeout() in angular to make things happen after x number of seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've given very little to go on but generally:

JS (make sure to load $timeout and $scope as dependencies into controller):

```
$scope.showImage = function() {
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.isVisible = false;
    }, 2000);

    $scope.isVisible = true;
};
```

HTML (ID's aren't needed at all, just to point out what's what):

```
<div ng-show="isVisible" id="saveConfirmImg"></div>
<button ng-click="showImage()" id="saveButton"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most I'll give you since I don't see any code:

`<div ng-show="loading"></div>`

```
$scope.loading = false;

$scope.onClick = function() {
    $scope.loading = true;
    saveData(data).then(function()) {
        $scope.loading = false;
    }
}
```